# How to check if two or more variables are set true

Tags: jquery

I have some bigger form with lots of radios and checkboxes, and whatever. I am performing several checks to return different messages based on the users input. I am all fine with that. There are overall 9 different scenarios and I am currently storing them as true or false in single vars:

```
var scenario_one; 
var scenario_two;
var scenario_three;
var scenario_four;
var scenario_five;
var scenario_six;
var scenario_seven;
var scenario_eight;
var scenario_nine;

$('input:radio[name="opt1"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Yes'){
       scenario_one = true;
      } else {
       scenario_one = false;
      };
  });

// ... and so on until all scenarios are checked ...
```

Now here comes my question: how ca I if-check **wether there are two or more vars are set to "true"**? so I can perform somethin like this:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
if ( /* Check if 2 oder more of var are set true */ ){
        alert('Some nice alert message');
    };
});
```

It just feels like this should not be too difficult but I am running out of ideas on this.

Comment: Do you want the count of all `true` scenarios to be more than 2? Or two specific variables being true?

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to replace your variables with an array of booleans to control this dynamically.

```
/*Replace all your variables with this*/
var scenarios = []


$('input:radio[name="opt1"]').change(function(){
      /* This will assign true/false to scenario[1]*/
      scenario[1] = ($(this).val() == 'Yes');
});

/* so on for the other scenarios*/

/* Then, when you need it... */

if (countTrue(scenario) >= 2) {

    alert("Two or more scenarios are true!");

}
```

Where `countTrue` is

```
function countTrue(arr) {
    var count = 0;
    arr.forEach(function(el){
        if(el){
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should make use of an array to make this happen

something like:

```
var scenarios = [];

$('input:radio').change(function(){
    //get the number of the scenario to change
    var scenario = $(this).attr("name").substr($(this).attr("name").length - 1);
    if($(this).val() == 'Yes'){
        scenarios[scenario] = true;
    } else {
        scenarios[scenario] = false;
    };
});

$('#button').click(function(){
    var count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < scenarios.length; i++) { 
        //if scenario equals true add to counter
        if(scenarios[i] == true)
            count++;

        //if counter is equal or superior to 2 alert and stop the for loop      
        if(count >= 2){
            alert('Some nice alert message');
            break;
        }

    }
});
```

[working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmkLevd2/2/) - Updated